# If a random variable has an atom at zero, does it have a density?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Let $Y$ be a random variable with distribution function
$$
F_Y(x) = \begin{cases}
0 &\quad x<0\\
p &\quad x=0\\
p + (1-p)F_X(x) &\quad x>0
\end{cases}
$$
where $X$ is a continuous random variable.

**My first question is if $Y$ has a density, despite the mass at 0? Moreover, is there a way to express $Y$ as a linear combination of other random variables, like a mixture?** For instance
$$
Y = (1-B)X + B\delta
$$
where $B$ is Bernoulli and $\delta$ is a degenerate r.v. at zero.

Comment: No, $Y$ does not have a density, due to mass at zero. Your representation as a mixture is correct assuming $B \sim \text{Bernoulli}(p)$. Also note that $\delta=0$, so you can simplify to $Y=(1-B)X$.

Comment: Measures with densities (w.r.t. Lebesgue measure) cannot have atoms (that is what the Radon-Nikodym theorem is all about)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @angryavian and @Oliver Díaz mentioned, indeed the distribution does not have a density due to the atom at zero. Moreover, the representation
$$
Y= (1-B)X + B\delta_{\{0\}} = (1-B)X
$$
correctly establishes the distribution $F_Y$ provided, assuming $X$ is a positive r.v. (which is not assumed on the question but should). Indeed
$$
\begin{aligned}
F_Y(y) &= P(Y\leq y)\\
&= P(Y\leq y | B = 0)P(B=0) + P(Y\leq y | B = 1)P(B = 1) \\
&= P(X\leq y)(1-p) + P(0 \leq y)p\\
&= F_X(y)(1-p) + \pmb{1}_{\{y\geq 0\}}p
\end{aligned}
$$
which is the same c.d.f. as the one in the question.